# How to select data from SQLite table using restrictions stored in file?

Tags: sqlite

I need to select data from my SQLite table using restrictions on field NAME where names are stored in names.txt file

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = (names are stored in names.txt file)
> ```

names.txt is ascii file with one column. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will work

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable(mycol VARCHAR(100))

.separator ","

.import names.txt #myTable

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name in (select mycol from #myTable)
```

Comment: @user2579566, try accepting it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes @Rahul !) It helped me! Thank you very much! But why do you use VARCHAR(100) instead of dynamic TEXT?

Comment: @user2579566, that's just an example to show that the task can be achieved this way; no specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Python to query SQLite :
http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

In Python, reading the text file into a list is as simple as :

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

then you can use this list as part of your SQL query